# Performance: Calculations inside query, ES vs Mysql

Tags: elasticsearch

Calculation in select query which is faster, mysql or elastic search? Why?

```
{
"query" : {
  ...
  },
    "script_fields" : {
         "gross_profit" : {
                 script: "((((doc['price_in_cents'].value * 100)/(100 +#{location.gst_rate})) - doc['cost_in_cents'].value)*(doc['quantity'].value)) "
                          }
           }
       }
```

or

```
   SELECT ((price_in_cents*100)/100/(100+#{location.gst_rate})) - cost_in_cents * quantity) as gross_profit FROM ...


   location.gst_rate is a dynamic variable (Note: Using ruby on rails syntax)
```

Following is my mysql schema (it have many other columns and relations, not including since they are irrelevant here):

```
 Table Name: Sales
 Columns:
 sales_id : integer
 price_in_cents : double
 cost_in_cents : double
 quantity : tiny int

Elastic search Index:
Name: Sales
id: integer
price_in_cents : double
cost_in_cents : double
quantity : tiny int
```

Comment: Looking at the problem from a different angle, if all the values are known beforehand why not storing the `gross_profit` in your table/index as well? There wouldn't be any question of which one is faster, right?

Comment: @val That is good way. But (price_in_cents*100)/100/(100+ **15** ), The "15" in the calculation is run time calculated, actually I am passing a variable there, it is like    SELECT ((price_in_cents*100)/100/(100+ #{location.gst_rate})) - cost_in_cents * quantity) as gross_profit FROM ...    Note: About syntax, I am using ruby on rails

Comment: Ok that makes sense, then, it wasn't clear from the queries you showed in your question, maybe you should update it to include that fact and mention that the 15 is a dynamic variable.